# Deserialize JSON into an object, and then run a foreach loop to add into a listview

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization, system.text.json

I've been struggling to deserialize an JSON request return from the IGDB API that I'm using for my application. I've managed to deserialize successfully in another part of my project, however this JSON has multiple values which I'm not sure how to correctly convert into object members. I'm constantly receiving System.Text.Json exceptions.

My GameListObject class is set as:

```
 public class GameListObject
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public string GameID { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string GameName { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("release_dates")]
        public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Try statement for API request and return:

```
//On search box content change
private async void gamehub_search_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<GameListObject> dataList = new ObservableCollection<GameListObject>();
    gamehub_list.ItemsSource = dataList;
    dataList.Clear();

    var SearchQuery = gamehub_search.Text;

    try
    {
        // Construct the HttpClient and Uri
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://api.igdb.com/v4/games");

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Client-ID", App.GlobalClientidIGDB);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + App.GlobalAccessIGDB);
        //Debug.WriteLine("Request Headers: ");

        // Construct the JSON to post
        HttpStringContent content = new HttpStringContent($"search \"{SearchQuery}\"; fields name,release_dates.human;");
        Debug.WriteLine("Request Contents: " + content);

        // Post the JSON and wait for a response
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(
            uri,
            content);

        // Make sure the post succeeded, and write out the response
        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var httpResponseBody = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("Request Response: " + httpResponseBody);

        //Deserialise the return output into game id, game name and release date
        GameListObject gamelistobject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GameListObject>(httpResponseBody);


        foreach (GameListObject GameListObject in gamelistobject) //Receiving error under 'gamelistobject'
        {
            //Add new item to the ListView
            GameListObject newitem = new GameListObject() { GameID = gamelistobject.GameID, GameName = gamelistobject.GameName, ReleaseDate = gamelistobject.ReleaseDate };
            dataList.Add(newitem);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine($"id: {gamelistobject.GameID}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"name: {gamelistobject.GameName}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"release_dates: {gamelistobject.ReleaseDate}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Note: Receiving error within the Foreach statement: Under 'gamelistobject' stating "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'GameHubs.GameListObject' because it does not contain public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

An example of a return JSON statement from the API:

```
{
    "id": 277,
    "name": "Battlefield 2",
    "release_dates": [
      {
        "id": 52086,
        "human": "Jun 21, 2005"
      },
      {
        "id": 52087,
        "human": "Jun 22, 2005"
      },
      {
        "id": 52088,
        "human": "Jun 24, 2005"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 89571,
    "name": "Battlefield V: Deluxe Edition",
    "release_dates": [
      {
        "id": 157810,
        "human": "Nov 16, 2018"
      },
      {
        "id": 157811,
        "human": "Nov 16, 2018"
      },
      {
        "id": 157812,
        "human": "Nov 16, 2018"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: 1. your JSON invalid. If that array of objects, it have to be wrapped by [] 2. you trying to parse list as object and enumerate object. Try `GameListObject[] gamelistobjects = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GameListObject[]>(httpResponseBody);` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use List instead of GameListObject, and you dont need foreach loop in this case

```
//Deserialise the return output into game id, game name and release date
   List<GameListObject> gamelistobjects = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<GameListObject>>(httpResponseBody);


   ObservableCollection<GameListObject> dataList = 
new ObservableCollection<GameListObject>(gamelistobjects);
```

or even one line would be ok

```
 ObservableCollection<GameListObject> dataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<GameListObject>>(json);
```

test

```
foreach (var item in dataList)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"id: {item.GameID}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"name: {item.GameName}");

         if(item.ReleaseDates!=null)
        foreach (var date in item.ReleaseDates)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"releaseDate: {date.Human}");
        }
    }
```

output

```
d: 277
name: Battlefield 2
releaseDate: Jun 21, 2005
releaseDate: Jun 22, 2005
releaseDate: Jun 24, 2005
id: 89571
name: Battlefield V: Deluxe Edition
releaseDate: Nov 16, 2018
releaseDate: Nov 16, 2018
releaseDate: Nov 16, 2018
```

and try this clasess

```
public partial class GameListObject
    {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long GameID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string GameName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("release_dates")]
    public ObservableCollection<ReleaseDate> ReleaseDates { get; set; }
}

public partial class ReleaseDate
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("human")]
    public string Human { get; set; }
}

public partial class ReleaseDate
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("human")]
    public string Human { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've added those, and it seems not to be adding anything to the list view. How am I meant to add the items into the list view? Do I still use the `GameListObject newitem = new GameListObject() { GameId = dataList.GameId, GameName = gamelistobject.GameName, ReleaseDate = gamelistobject.ReleaseDate };
                dataList.Add(newitem);`?

Because if I try print 'dataList' I receive: "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[ReviewR.GameHubs+GameListObject]" as the output.

Comment: @ThatGuyJacobee I updated my answer

Comment: It's working great, thank you very much! Just to edit onto your solution, I added an if statement to only print releaseDate if item.ReleaseDates != null otherwise if a game doesn't have a release date set it would throw an error.

`if (item.ReleaseDates != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var date in item.ReleaseDates)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine($"releaseDate: {date.Human}");
                        }
                    }`